# How to get text translation framework for any programming languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, embedded-linux

I am writing an application. Such as Chinese/Japanese/Arabic/etc to English or English to french/dutch/russian. I do not have internet, where the project will use, so i can not use other existing internet translation services. So i am trying to collect a framework for my language such as Java or C or Python or D.

How to get Google like text translation framework as open source/free to use for quality text translation or which other framework can be used for this project?

Challenge is:

```
"how are you?" = hoe gaat het
               = 你是如何
               = お元気ですか？
               = كيف حالك
               = आप कैसे हैं
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the question.

If you want your application to display various user messages in several human languages, you need to worry about localization or internationalization. With C or C++ on Posix, functions like [gettext](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettext) are relevant.

Several libraries or frameworks also provide related features. As an example, Qt has [its internationalization framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/internationalization.html)

Or do you want to automatically translate text from one human language to another? This is an entire research domain ([machine translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_translation)), so prepare to get a PhD on that; you'll need several years of hard work (and the results are still not very satisfactory).

Comment: automatically translate text.